# How do you check if points within a grid are connected vertically/horizontally? (1 away from each other)

Tags: c++

Let's just use 1 as there is a point, and 0 if nothing.

For example, the grid:

0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 1

0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 1

would not be connected together, while

0 0 1 0 0

0 1 1 0 0

0 0 1 1 0

0 0 0 1 1

is.

I feel as if using something like BFS would be horribly inefficient for something that should probably be fairly simple; is there any other option?

Comment: have a look at the problem called percolation. It's the same! have a look at this video https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/lecture/OLXM8/union-find-applications You can use union and find to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

BFS or DFS is indeed the proper solution. The rest is just a matter of taking advantage of properties of rectilinear grid (raster) for implementing such search algorithms in more efficient manner, preferably more efficient than a "straightforward" implementation. For example, some classic 4-way raster [scanline flood-fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) is a good approach for searching connected components in your grid (see the "Scanline fill" section).

Answer (score 1):

The best asymptotic complexity for this kind of problem comes from the union find algorithm using rank and path compression.

Union find associates each new point with a group name that is either unique, taken from left or top neighbor, or *unifies* the groups (by making a link from one group to the other).

In the end all parents of all initially unique groups point to same item, in which case the set is connected.

[Further reading with c++ source code](https://brilliant.org/wiki/disjoint-set-data-structure/)

[Further reading for image processing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/category/connected-components/)

```
#include "catch.hpp"
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
T parent(std::vector<T> &links, T item)
{
    if (item == 0)
        return item;
    while (links[(size_t)item - 1] != item)
        item = links[(size_t)item - 1];
    // Should implement path compression
    return item;
}

template <typename T, int N, int M>
bool is_connected(T(&array)[N][M])
{
    // Assumption is that the type T is large enough to hold N*M/2 distinct entries
    // Thus we can use/modify the array itself to record (roots) of distinct labels
    // Of course we could copy the array into a vector of type size_t
    std::vector<T> parents;

    for (auto j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            T &current = array[j][i];
            if (!current)
                continue;
            T left = i ? parent(parents, array[j][i - 1]) : 0;
            T above = j ? parent(parents, array[j - 1][i]) : 0;
            if (left == 0)
            {
                if (above)
                    current = above;
                else
                    parents.emplace_back(current = (T)(parents.size() + 1));
            }
            else
            {
                // Todo: implement rank based selection of joining the sets
                current = left;
                if (above != 0 && above != left)
                    parents[(size_t)above - 1] = left;
            }
        }
    }

    // Check that all intermediate disjoint sets have now a single root
    if (parents.size() == 0)
        return false;   // is empty set connected or not?

    auto last_item = parents.back();
    auto root = parent(parents, last_item);
    parents.pop_back();
    for (auto &group : parents)
    {
        if (root != parent(parents, group))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

SCENARIO("Is connected")
{
    int arr[4][4] = {
        { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };
    auto foo = is_connected(arr);
    CHECK(foo == true);
    arr[3][1] = 0;
    CHECK(is_connected(arr) == false);
}
```