# Merge coordinate vectors if they have one coordinate that is a neighbor of another

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `vector<vector<coord>> list`, something like:

```
[
    [(1,0),(1,1)],
    [(0,3),(1,3)],
    [(2,0),(2,1),(3,1)],
    [(2,3),(3,3),(3,2)]
]
```

I need to merge each vector with neighboring coordinates in another. So, for example, in the vector above, `2,0` is neighbor of `1,0` in the first vector of the list. Therefore, the `list[0]` and `list[3]` are merged.

Leaving the result to be:

```
[
    [(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),(3,1)],
    [(0,3),(1,3)],
    [(2,3),(3,3),(3,2)]
]
```

This is just one merge though, this will continue until no longer possible or until only vector is left in the list.

Comment: What is the code you have written so far?

Comment: @SamuelKirschner - I haven't been able to come up with an algorithm for it and just stuck so, till now, I got nothing.

Comment: [Disjoint-set_data_structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to gain much help. However, after a very long night, I have found an answer. It seems horribly in-efficient, and mostly not very good but it works and provides the correct result. If someone can improve, please do so. :)

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ ){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < list[i].size() ; j++ ){
            // Method that provides a vector of neighboring coordinates
            auto ns = x.findneighbours(list[i][j]);
            for(int k = 0 ; k < ns.size() ; k++ ){
                for(int q = i+1 ; q < list.size() ; q++ ){
                    for(int w = 0 ; w < list[q].size() ; w++ ){
                        if( list[q][w]->id == ns[k]->id ){
                            list[i].insert( list[i].end(), list[q].begin(), list[q].end() );
                            list.erase(list.begin()+q);
                            if(list.size() == 1 ){
                                label = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if(label){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(label){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(label){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(label){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(label){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the need of `label`. but splitting in sub-function would ease to read.
BTW, your algo seems wrong: if only neighbors are `list[2]` with both `list[0]` and `list[1]`, you correctly merge `list[0]` and `list[2]`, but you gorget the final merge `list[0]` `list[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest method is the disjoint-set algorithm, as suggested in the comments.

Still, the first problem is locating the nearest neighbors, which is anywhere between O(N^2), O(N*logN) to O(N) complexity problem, depending on other restrictions.

- O(N^2) -- brute force without additional storage
- O(N*logN) -- group the points by delaunay tessellation
- O(N) -- trade size to speed and allocate a 2d-array/image of S[ydim][xdim]

If the coordinates in the list are not arbitrary big, I'd suggest just plotting all lists in a 2d-array, which makes searching neighbors O(1) problem (per element). Also when plotting Nth list and encountering a *label* of 1..(N-1) in the neighbourhood of inserted pixels, one can immediately join the Nth list with the previously inserted list.

Then use flood-fill or disjoint-set (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46822536/1716339))